# weird problem with django templates

Tags: django, templates

while working on templates weird problem occured:

when templates are being rendered (i guess), in code, right before the
doctype, strange character is being placed. I call it "strange"
because if I select it, copy it and try to paste nothing is pasted.
This "dot" is seen only if I do "view source" in webkit browsers.

now, layout breaks.

while checking rendered code in internet explorer web developer
toolbar, I've seen that also doctype is pasted within body tag, so I
have an impression that both, opening and closing, head tags are
somehow being ignored.
(i've checked it now and yes, If I take out opening and closing head
tags from my template, that is exactly what happens).

this is rendered code in ie web developer toolbar:
http://i48.tinypic.com/noby81.gif

please help!

Comment: Uhm, why is the DOCTYPE inside the BODY and not the very first thing in the file? I don't know if that's related to the problem, but it's definitely wrong.

Comment: Yeah you should probably sanitize that HTML before you try working with it.

Comment: What weird character are you talking about? I see none in the screenshot.

Comment: well, i am sorry if I wasn't clear, but that exactly is a problem. in template doctype IS the first thing on the very first line. but when it is being rendered browsers just seem to ingore completely instances of opening and closing "head" tag. 
I am sorry I coulnd'nt provide second screenshot with the "dot" itself, cause I couldn't place to links in my post. Let's see if I can in comment. 
Strange dot appearing before the doctype:
http://i47.tinypic.com/osu905.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps what you're seeing is the Byte Order Mark, or its byte-reversed counterpart, the Zero Width No-Break Space. Some text editors place it at the beginning of text files in order to help detect the encoding of the file. You can use a tool such as od to see the exact byte sequence.

Comment: Thanks a lot. that really was BOM. Just turned it off in Komodo Edit preferences, resaved the file and now everything is fine. Happy new year.!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to resolve problems with BOM in templates is to change FILE_CHARSET in your settings.py to 'utf-8-sig'

Answer (score 0):

I think that answer is easy. Open all of your files (html) envolved on extends or includes with the vim editor. Probably you will see in the first line some strange characters. Remove this and your problem is resolved. I don't know what the reason for this but it resolve the problem.